# Why does my LIKE search return everything?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I am trying to make an image search in my page full of images.

Whatever I search, it always returns all images with tag info in the database.

I made it so when someone enters text into the searchbox, the page is redirected to this:

```
ob_start();

$input = abs($_GET['input']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `photo`.`photo` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$input'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$image = $data['image'];

if ($rows==0) {
    echo 'no results found';
}  else {
    $jpgimage = imagecreatefromstring($image);

    $image_width = imagesx($jpgimage);
    $image_height = imagesy($jpgimage);

    $new_size = ($image_width + $image_height)/($image_width*($image_height/45));
    $new_width = $image_width * $new_size;
    $new_height = $image_height * $new_size;

    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    imagecopyresized($new_image, $jpgimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);
    $imagearray = imagejpeg($new_image, null);
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    echo $imagearray;
}
```

The photos are stored as BLOBS so here I turn them into jpegs and resize them.

Most of this is just re-sizing the images but I have no idea why the LIKE part in my mysql query line isn't working. It always gives me all the images with any pictures that have tags.

Comment: what do you get from `var_dump($input)` ?

Comment: What is your input suppose to be? With `abs` being called on your input it looks like it will end up being null if its not a number.

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but for me, it looks as if you're not putting a proper SQL query together. Use a parametrized query with `$input` and you should be fine. (And why the `abs()` in the `$input` assignment?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect $input is empty.  If your variable $input is null or empty string it will create a where clause:

```
 SELECT * FROM `photo`.`photo` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%'
```

This will match wildcard '%' to everything.

Comment: I would have expected `tags` to be a string.  But it is obviously going to be a positive numeric value...?  `WHERE `tags` LIKE '%4.5'"` - That just doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: Yes it was the abs, dont even know why I put that, must not have been thinking straight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is the abs on the first line. If you do an abs of a text string you get a zero.

Comment: Yes it was the abs, dont even know why I put that, must not have been thinking straight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You code use `$input = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['input'])` for a more secure code.
There is no need to use the `abs()` function in your case.